# gcc can not combine -flto with -g, so how to generate debug info?

Tags: c++, gcc, linker

The gcc manual says:

> Combining -flto with -g is currently experimental and expected to
>   produce unexpected results.

And I found if use -flto, the -g is ignored.

But I really want -g so that I can get more info when I check a core dump(gdb a.out core.xxxx).

How to workaround it if I do need -flto (I use many pimpl pattern) and need to analyze the core dump? What should I do?

Update:
The code uses many pimpl pattern and I used the perf and flame graph to analyze the cpu usage. Some tiny functions do use too much cpu. And I am not want to debug the code, I just want the debuginfo when I need to analyze the core dump.

Comment: The manual is a bit flippant there.  It is basically saying that using the `-g` option and the `-flto` option together has undocumented results that may change arbitrarily between GCC versions, releases, or even builds.  The developers are playing with the combination, albeit not necessarily actively, and they will probably settle on and document some behavior in a future version.  That behavior might be anything, including "gcc fails with an error".  Unless you are developing GCC itself, you would be wise to stay away from features with such expressly undocumented behavior.

Comment: @JohnBollinger So how to workaround it if I do need -flto and need to analyze the core dump?

Comment: @alpha: Debug the code before building with LTO? There are plenty of optimizations that make code meaningless in a debugger, this is just one more of them. Pull out the disassembler.

Comment: @ZanLynx Not debug, I mean if the program crash, I need to gdb xyz.out core.xxx.

Comment: @alpha, as far as I am aware, there is no workaround, in the sense that `-flto` and `-g` simply do not work together.  I note that the docs for my version of GCC put this a little more explicitly than those of yours: "Combining '-flto' with '-g' is [...] expected to produce wrong results."  If you want debugging information for your program, then, remove `-flto`.  Indeed, I urge you to think about whether you actually *need* the link-time optimizations; they are off by default, and it may be that they don't actually help you much.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The code uses many pimpl pattern and I used the perf and flame graph to analyze the cpu usage. Some tiny functions do use too much cpu. And I am not want to debug the code, I just want the debuginfo when I need to analyze the core dump.

Comment: @alpha, it does not matter in what context or for what purpose you want the debugging info.  When you compile with `-flto`, you cannot have it.

Comment: As of today, I don't see the caveat in the question in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options. I do see: _Link-time optimization does not work well with generation of debugging information on systems other than those using a combination of ELF and DWARF._ For what it's worth, we've been using `-flto` together with `-g` for a couple of years with the `arm-non-eabi-gcc` without much difficulty.